# Addressing specific item within HTML string using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to populate a webform and I am struggling to correctly address the field I want to populate.

This is one line of the table in HTML

[image]

Here is the overall HTML structure
[image]

```
<th>
    <label for="location_sales_target_2_2022_15_target_val">2022w15 (03/04)</label>
</th>

<td>
    <input name="location_sales_target[2][2022/15][id]" id="location_sales_target_2_2022_15_id" type="hidden" value="12751">
    <input name="location_sales_target[2][2022/15][target_val]" id="location_sales_target_2_2022_15_target_val" type="text" value="0.00">
</td>
<td>£2,097.33</td>
```

I need to be able to address the final value field and update its value.

This is the VBA code I have so far. My VBA is limited and this is copied from online and modified.

```
Sub IEWebScrape1()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer 'Reference to Microsoft Internet Controls
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
 
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://"
        
        'we add a loop to be sure the website is loaded and ready.
        'Does not work consistently. Cannot be relied upon.
        Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE 'Equivalent = .ReadyState <> 4
            ' DoEvents - worth considering. Know implications before you use it.
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 'Wait 1 second, then check again.
        Loop
        
             
        'Print info in immediate window
        With .document 'the source code HTML "below" the displayed page.
            Debug.Print.getElementById("sf_admin_container").Children(1).getElementsByTagName("tr")(16).textContent
           
        End With '.document
        
     '   .Quit 'close the application window
   End With 'ie
    
End Sub
```

The VBA code produces this result, which confirms it is correctly referencing the record I am trying to reference.

2022W15 (03/04)

£2,097.33

How do I correctly address the specific element within the record?

Comment: I have now amended my code to include a further .Children element and this isolates the specific row in the record but I still cannot access the specific element. I am researching in InStr to see if this is what I need to use.

Comment: where is `sf_admin_container` in your html codes?

Comment: The sf_admin_container is the parent level for the <tr> record I have shown above.  The table itself is a form to input financial targets for stores. There are 25 stores x 52 weeks. Each store has its own div which is sf_admin_list, but I want to  access all of the <tr> records at the same time. I have added another image of the HTML above

Comment: I have solved the problem now.  Obviously completely confused about using getElement statements. Problem solved by correct use of getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem now. Obviously completely confused about using getElement statements. Problem solved by correct use of getElementById

Comment: You may post your final code to be accepeted as an answer. This is not an answer.